# Changing the font of all text fields at once in QGIS

Tags: qgis, font

The order came from above last minute to change the font to Arial in my QGIS maps. There are many text boxes, legends etc.
And 9 different maps.

How do I change the font of all text objects at once in a map?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Open you QGIS project using a texteditor of your choice. If your project is saved to `.qgz`, unzip it first.

Hit `ctrl + H` (search & replace) and search for `fontFamily="currentfontname" fontItalic`. As replacement you fill in `fontFamily="Arial" fontItalic`. Replace all occurences and save the file. Reopen the project in QGIS and double check.

This should replace the font for all layout items, but not for symbologies, since those seem to be noted as `fontFamily="Arial" useSubstitutions="0" fontItalic="0"`.

Comment: Oh, maybe save a copy of your project, if something goes really wrong.